# How to show that the quadratic variation of $p$ is $t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have to prove that $[p,p] = t$ with $p$ defined in the following way:

$$ N_u = \sum_{i=1}^n(B_t^i)^2 $$
$$ p = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^t \frac{B_u^i dB_u^i}{\sqrt{N_u}}$$

Theoretically i know that Brownian motion of all independent n- dimensional Brownian motion will be zero for above term and i will be only left with dependent BM, but how to mathematically denote these steps?

Comment: $$dp_t=\sum_i \frac{B_t^i dB_t^i}{\sqrt{N_t}}\implies d\langle p,p\rangle_t=\sum_i \sum_j\frac{B_t^i }{\sqrt{N_t}}\frac{B_t^j}{\sqrt{N_t}}d\langle B^i,B^j\rangle_t=\ldots$$

Comment: Write an answer then?

Comment: This is my solution                                                                                              $$ d<p,p>_t = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{B_t^i . B_t^j}{\sqrt(N_t) \sqrt(N_t)} d<B^i,B^j>_t $$
        $$= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(B_t^i)^2}{(B_t^i)^2} dt $$

Comment: ?? What is $N_t$ already?